# Adding & Displaying Parse Profile Pic in iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

My app is a kind of social media, where users can post various things to be seen by others using the app.  I would like to have it set up in Parse so that when they see the Table View of posts, the profile picture for each user is displayed as the cell's `imageView`.  However, I'm not quite sure what the best way would be to do this.

On my core data, I have '_User' which has all the Users' info created at sign-up.  I also have another database named 'Posts', which contains all the posted materials.  I could upload a file to 'Posts' with each post, but that seems like it would use too much data and take too long.  So, I thought, I can just put a profile picture in '_User', but here is the issue:

All the posts are on 'Posts', so I use PFQueryTableViewController to load the class 'Posts'.  If my profile pic is in '_User' can I call one item from this at the same time?

Please help, as I'm just a bit confused on what the best way to do this would be.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically a good idea to store the image of the user against the user (or something separate like a `UserProfile`) object if you want the same image for all `Posts` by the same user. This becomes an even more obvious design decision if you want to allow the user to change their image, and have all the `Posts` display the new image.

You will be able to query the `Post` for the associated `User` object, and then retrieve the `PFFile` via its URL for that user. To make it faster, and avoid repeated queries to Parse for the same data, you can use `cachePolicy` attribute on your `PFQuery` for retrieving your `Posts` and `Users`, as well as image caching locally. That will significantly speed up your image loading, as well as reduce the API hits on Parse.